Fundamental group of boundary of disk glued with a twist
Consider the space $X$ obtained by gluing the boundary of a $2-$ disk onto itself by the relation $z \sim z^n$, where $n>1$ is a positive integer and the boundary $S^1$ is viewed as the unit disk in the complex plane. My goal is to compute the fundamental group of $X$. It was mentioned to me by colleagues that $\pi_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}_n,$ and I am trying to prove it.
My first instinct is to cover $X$ with a cover $\{A,B\}$ where $A$ is the the space $X$ minus the "tip" point, and $B$ is a small open disk containing the point, and then apply The Van-Kampen's theorem. It appears to me that $A$ can be retracted onto its boundary, which I think is a wedge of $n$ copies of $S^1$, which has fundamental group the free product of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. Is this correct?
Assuming the above is correct, I see that the intersection of $A$ and $B$ is contractible to an $S^1$, and its image is included in $\pi_1(X)$ as $a_1\dots a_n$, where $a_i$ is a generator for the $i^{th}$ circle's fundamental group. Since $\pi_1(B)$ is trivial, the fundamental group of $X$ should be the group with presentation $\langle a_1,\dots,a_n \mid a_1\dots a_n \rangle.$ But this seems to be a different group than $Z_n$, and I am not sure where I went wrong. Any correction or a separate derivation of $\pi_1(X)$ would be appreciated.

$A$ is homotopic to $S^1$ (but an $S^1$ which spins around $n$ times faster than $A \cap B$). Try to work out the examples $n=2,3$ with drawings to convince yourself.

In particular, note that for $n = 2$ the space $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2$.

Your instinct to cover $X$ with $\{A, B\}$ as given is great, but you're not visualizing $A$ correctly. Let me write $\partial X \subset X$ for the copy of $S^1$ you're gluing a disk to. Then the $A$ deformation retracts onto $\partial X$ (in fact $A$ is homeomorphic to the mapping cylinder of the map $\phi_n\colon S^1 \to S^1$, $z \mapsto z^n$), not an $n$-fold wedge of $S^1$'s.
Before working out the rest of the argument, let me recast it in a slightly more "rigid" light that makes the proof a bit easier. Given any continuous map $f\colon X \to Y$, let me introduce two spaces, namely the mapping cylinder
$$
    M_f := (X \times I \sqcup Y) / (x, 1) \sim f(x) 
$$
and the mapping cone
$$
    C_f := M_f / (X \times \{0\})
$$
of $f$. In other words, $M_f$ is obtained from taking the cylinder $X \times I$ and attaching its "bottom" (or "top", depending on which way you look at it) to $Y$ via $f$, and $C_f$ is obtained from $M_f$ by collapsing the "top" (or "bottom") to a point. Note that the space $X$ you're describing is homeomorphic to $C_{\phi_n}$ where $\phi_n\colon S^1 \to S^1$, $\phi_n(z) = z^n$ is the $n$th power map, via a homeomorphism carrying the "tip point" to the collapsed $X \times \{0\}$ and $\partial X$ to $Y = S^1$ in the above construction (I'll leave the details to you).
Note then that any mapping cylinder deformation retracts onto $Y$ via the homotopy $h_t\colon M_f \to M_f$ given by $h_t(y) = y$ for all $y \in Y$ and $h_t(x, s) = (x, t + (1 - t)s)$ for all $(x, s) \in X \times I$, i.e. by compressing the cylinder down onto $Y$. In particular, we have that $h_1(x, s) = f(x)$ for all $(x, s) \in X \times I$.
We then have the following general statement:

Proposition: If $X$ and $Y$ are path-connected, then $\pi_1 C_f \cong \pi_1 Y / \langle f_*(\pi_1 X) \rangle$ (here the angle brackets denote taking the normal closure).

In particular, we thus find in your case that $\pi_1 X \cong \pi_1 S^1 / (\phi_n)_*(\pi_1 S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z} / n$, seeing as $\phi_n$ induces multiplication by $n$ on $\pi_1$.
Proof: Consider the open cover $\{A, B\}$ of $C_f$ where $A = X \times (1/4, 1] \cup Y$ and $B = X \times [0, 3/4)$ (in analogy to your cover $\{A, B\}$). Then $B$ is contractible (via any deformation retraction of $[0, 3 / 4)$ onto $\{0\}$), $A$ deformation retracts onto $X \times [1 / 2, 1] \cup Y \cong M_f$, and $A \cap B = X \times (1/4, 3/4)$ deformation retracts onto $X \times \{1/2\}$. In particular, we can then compute the induced map of the inclusion $\iota\colon A \cap B \hookrightarrow A$ as follows: Represent any class of $\pi_1(A \cap B)$ by a loop $\gamma\colon S^1 \to X \times \{1/2\}$. This can be taken to be the "top" of the mapping cylinder $A$ deformation retracts onto just mentioned, so the deformation retraction $h_t$ from above provides us with a homotopy from $h_0 \circ \gamma = \gamma$ to $h_1 \circ \gamma = f \circ \gamma$, which is precisely to say that $\iota_*[\gamma] = f_*[\gamma]$ in $\pi_1 A$.
Putting everything together, van Kampen now tells us that
$$
    \pi_1 C_f \cong \pi_1 A *_{\langle\iota_*\pi_1(A \cap B)\rangle} \pi_1 B \cong \pi_1 A *_{\langle\iota_*\pi_1(A \cap B)\rangle} 1 \cong \pi_1 A / \langle\iota_*(\pi_1(A \cap B))\rangle \cong \pi_1 Y / \langle f_*(\pi_1 X)\rangle
$$
$\Box$

There's of course no need to make this detour over mapping cones, strictly speaking, but the advantage is twofold: Firstly, on $M_f$ and $C_f$ you have very simple "coordinates" that allow you to rigorously define maps and and homotopies, and secondly you can derive results in greater generality, as evidenced.

Thank you for the detailed solution, that was very helpful.
